# how to speed up the application in sleep mode(Android Studio Kotlin)?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

My program has a local server that sends requests and receives information from there. everything works through the foreground service, that is, the application is never unloaded from memory(working as a daemon), it always works.  The problem is that after some time of inactivity of the smartphone, requests start working not once every 3 seconds, but every 30-80 seconds (approximately).  is it possible to somehow speed up the work in this case?  After unlocking the smartphone, the speed returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to somehow speed up the work in this case?

Yes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

But you should have a good reason for this.

Read more on Doze Mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

You can use [a push notification](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#using_fcm) to wake up the device for your use case. Ask your assistant to find device -> send push notification -> app wakes and up does what you want.

Comment: Hello! If I am not mistaken, this feature allows you to prompt the user to turn off the energy saving for this offer.  But even in this way, the delay still remains, as I said, a delay of one minute.  I should have clarified that the application does not save battery anyway.

Comment: is there any other way to speed up the application?  answer, please

Comment: I can explain why this is necessary.  the thing is, I made my own voice assistant.  sometimes I lose my smartphone in the house and ask the assistant to find it, sometimes I have to wait a minute for the phone to ring, I would like to reduce the delay by at least 4 times

Comment: Follow the documentation I linked to already. Use a push notification. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#using_fcm